# Get x and y position of an empty following a curve

Tags: scripting, bezier-curves

So what I would like to do is print the x and y position of an object that follows a path in Blender from start to finish. At the end there should be an array of [x,y]. I have no idea how to code inside of Blender, but I thought maybe some of you guys know how to easily do this or if there's a similar question that has already been answered.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me out here!

Answer (score 7):

### Example

Here is an example, based on this setup:

[image: An empty and a spiral]

The layout consists of an empty and a curve, both created at the origin.

using this *Follow Path* constraint on the empty:

[image: The follow path constraint].

Note that the *Animate Path* button has been pressed

If we look at the path's object data properties, under *Path Animation* we find:

[image: Path Animation data].

The important bit here being that *Path Animation* is set.

The following code, given this setup, will produce your array:

```py
import bpy

object = bpy.data.objects["Empty"]
curve = bpy.data.objects["Spiral"].data
frames = curve.path_duration

increment = 1

co_list = []
for desired_time in range(0, frames+1, increment):
    curve.eval_time = desired_time
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
    co_list.append((object.matrix_world[0][3], object.matrix_world[1][3]))
```

### Explanation

The first two lines of code after the `import` select the object and the curve that it is following.  We take it as given that the object has the follow path constraint.

You need to replace those with two lines that accomplish your goal.

The next line reads the `Frames` value for the Curve's *Path Animation* settings.  That's the total number of frames in your animation.  The evaluation time will run between 0 and that time.

We can subdivide the evaluation time as finally as we want, so we use `increment` to set that.  I picked 1, because that matches an increment of once per frame, which would make sense if you wanted the animation data on frames.

The loop increments the evaluation time of the path animation of the curve.  On each increment, it updates the view_layer so that the location of the empty will match the position it would have on the curve.

The position of the empty is taken from its world matrix.  Since this question isn't about how matrices are used in position calculation I'll just say that those two values are the resulting X and Y position of the empty *assuming it was created at the origin*, as this one was.

We make a tuple of the X and Y coordinates, and add them to the list.

At the end, `co_list` contains an array of x, y coordinates, representing each position of the empty as it moves along the curve one increment at a time.

### Bonus

The spiral is created using the built-in "Extra Curves" add-on.

[image: Adding a spiral]

This one has two changes from the default settings. *Turns* was set to 3 and *Radius Growth* was set to 1.0

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer and comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this incredible answer. From previous experiences (you can probably guess on which site) I was afraid of asking anything that isn't extremely complicated. This helped me a lot and gave me new confidence in asking simple and sometimes maybe stupid questions!

Comment: Thanks a lot for this incredible answer. From previous experiences (you can probably guess on which site) I was afraid of asking anything that isn't extremely complicated. This helped me a lot and gave me new confidence in asking simple and sometimes maybe stupid questions!

Answer (score 3):

If you just get the xy position, it has a simple way to print out.
Select the curve in object mode and run the script. The curve will convert to mesh.

```
import bpy, bmesh

bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH') # convert to mesh

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)

array = []
for vert in bm.verts:
    array.append((vert.co[0], vert.co[1]))

print(array)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

If you want animate the empty frame by frame:

```
import bpy, bmesh

bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH') # convert to mesh

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)

array = []
for vert in bm.verts:
    array.append((vert.co[0], vert.co[1]))

print(array)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')


# add a empty
bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES', align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))

oj = bpy.context.object

for i, xy in enumerate(array):
    oj.location = (xy[0], xy[1], 0)
    oj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=i)
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the coordinates of the converted mesh wouldn't match the positions of the empties at frame increments of the follow path evaluation time except rarely by coincidence.  It's an array of points on a curve not an array of positions through time.

Comment: agree, because the travel distance is not same